# What is the difference between these cin functions?

Tags: c++

So what is the difference between `cin.fail()`, `!(cin>>)` and `cin.get() !='/n'`?

I understand they are all ways of handling errors during input can someone explain what each of them does and what would i use certain one over the other ?

Comment: Find [a good reference site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) and you can look for yourself. As for which one to use, it really depends on situation.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i did find answer about cin.fail and ignore however i couldn't find any one explaining cin.get() !='/n'

Comment: @Justaname `cin.get() != '/n'` does not check for errors.  Also, you likely meant to say `'\n'`.

Comment: @DrewDormann pretty sure it can be used to check if the input failed that's why i want to understand how and why it does that .. and yes that's what i meant my bad

Comment: @Justaname All `cin.get() != '\n'` does is ask the question: "is the next character in the stream not a newline?" This is entirely unrelated to stream error handling.

Comment: @cdhowie i've seen it used as a way of handling wrong input such as if the user enters a character value into an integer type or any thing like that and it works .. would you kindly explain why ?

Comment: @Justaname I guess it depends what you mean by "error." What you're describing is a semantic error relating to *the input not being meaningful* while "error" to most C++ developers in the context of I/O streams is going to mean "an error condition on the stream," which means *the input operation failed.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Explanations**
The function `cin.fail()` returns true if the failure bit is set in the `cin` stream.

The expression `cin >>` will ignore spaces then attempt to read in the data type.  If the read fails, the `cin` status will be set to `failure`.  There is an overload that allows the return value of `operator>>` to be converted from failure to `bool`.

The expression `cin.get() != '\n'`, reads in a character from `cin`, then tests that character for newline (`'\n'`). *Note:  the character read from `cin` is deleted and not available for other purposes.*

The expressions are used for different purposes.

**Usages**

- `cin.fail()` -- to test the failure state of `cin`, after something
  has been read from `cin`.
- `cin >>` -- reads in an object from `cin`, using formatted input
  (e.g. converting textual number to internal format).  May be
  overloaded for other objects.
- `cin.get() != '\n'` -- Used when searching for a newline.  The
  character read is trashed after the comparison.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation .. if i may ask what do you mean "test it for new line " ?

Comment: The character read from `cin` is tested for `'\n'`.  The character sequence `'\n'` is referred to as a *newline*.  On some platforms, it represents Carriage Return (0x0d) *and* linefeed (0x0A).  Some platforms it represents only a linefeed.  Some platforms it represents only carriage return.

Comment: "There is an overload that allows the return value of `operator>>` to be converted from failure to `bool`." The way this is worded seems to imply that there is an overload of `operator>>` that allows the return value to be converted to `bool`, but I believe you meant that `std::istream` overloads `explicit operator bool`

Comment: @ThomasMatthews so if the cin fails the character is not there and that's how it finds out if the input failed or didn't ?                                        thanks alot for the help i really appreciate it

Comment: There are many ways that the input stream can fail.  See your [`std::istream::get()` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) for more information.